# Given the Following Code how Would i Change/Set my Silverlight WCF Service URI in code?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, dynamic, uri

Given the Following Code how Would i Change/Set my Silverlight WCF Service URI in code?

```
    mySvc.InsertPOCompleted += new EventHandler<SalesSimplicityPO_SL.POSvc.InsertPOCompletedEventArgs>(mySvc_InsertPOCompleted);
    mySvc.InsertPOAsync(InitialsTextBox.Text.ToString(), DescTextBox.Text.ToString(), ClientTextBox.Text.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(); 
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/POSystem/POSvc.svc")); 
POSvc.POSvcClient mySvc = new POSvc.POSvcClient(binding, address);
```